# reading text file lines into asp.net contentplaceholder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to ASP.Net and am trying to set up some content pages to work with my master page.
I currently have the following text hardcoded into an asp:contentplaceholder and it works just fine. I want to read lines in from a text file to produce those headlines and retain the current formatting. I tried using the  tag i need each line as a separate

tag. Below is the code in the content place holder. Id like to have this done in the Page_Load or the pre Init.

```
<p class="text1">---  We recently completed an evaluation for a large Ocean Tug fleet showing 70% particulate reduction, 11% NOx reduction and an 8% fuel economy improvement.</p>
<p class="text1">---  Our Product was added to the Grainger catalog as its primary emissions and fuel efficiency Catalyst.</p>
<p class="text1">---  Our Product is recommended by Mann-Hummel to promote better performance in Diesel Particulate Filters.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
IO.File.ReadAllLines()
```

method will read a text file and return to you an array of strings; one for each line of text.

You can then loop through that, building up the HTML string to place into the ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: yes I know how to do that but I dont know how to attach it to the contentplaceholder

Comment: A few different ways, at least.  The one I use most often is a LiteralControl.  placeholder.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("literal html and/or text goes here."))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    Dim Lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path)
    For Each f As String In Lines
        Response.Write("<p class='text1'>" & f & "</p>")
    Next
```

Edit: I noticed you want it inside a ContentPlaceHolder, therefore can't use `Response.Write`. If that's the case you can try using a `Literal` control and then append the previous code using `LiteralName.Text &= f`

Hopefully it helps!

Edit: Adding more code, supporting what @Brian M. has said:

```
Dim Content As String = String.Empty
Dim Lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Path)
For Each TxtFromFile As String In Lines
    Content &= "<p class='text1'>" & TxtFromFile & "<p>"
Next
Me.ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(Content))
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have no problem with the vb to read the lines and create the html I DO NOT know how to set it to the contentplaceholder

Comment: so place a literal control within the contentplaceholder?

Comment: To set it into the ContentPlaceHolder you can use a Literal control as I mentioned before.   <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literalContent"></asp:Literal>   Then from the code behind replace the Response.Write I included before to "literalContent.Text &=f"